# Transposition of characters in C

Tags: c, output, substitution

I have been working on a program in C that will do some simple math, convert the answer into hex, change the position of the first and second characters of the hex output with the third and fourth characters `(abcd->cdab)`.

I imagine that one way to do this is to convert the output into a string and then use a function like `strtok` to transpose those characters.

**How do I get the string to print the hex in cdab format rather than abcd?** For example: 03b1 to b103.

Here is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int f;
    int j;
    int x;
    float a = (1) ;
    int b = 750;
    float c = (a/b) ;
    float g = 0;
    float d = sinf(c+(c*g)) ;
    float e = d*1000;
    f = (int) e;
    printf( " 1/750 = %15.18f\n sine of 1/750 = %15.18f\n sine of 1/750 times 1000 = %15.18f\n that is %x in hex\n" ,c ,d,e,f ) ; 
    i = 0; // the initial value multiplied times c plus c
    do
    {
        float l = c * i; 
        float h = sinf(c+l) ;
        float k = h*1000; 
        j = (int) k; //  gets rid of everything after the decimal point
        printf("%f  %d 0%X" ,k,i,j); // %x for hex, the 3 inbetween is the hex length, \n for new line, the 0 before the rest adds a 0 to the hex.
        //char x[4];
        //sprintf(x, "0%x" ,j);
        //char str[2];
        //printf(" %c\n ", str);
        //std::string base= j;
        i++;
    }
    while (i < b+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question was "what's the best way to take a string 'abcd' and output 'cdab' if I read it right.

Comment: I want to change the order of a 4 digit hex value from a format of abcd to cdab-- just like Mr. Rankin's interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

After stuffing the hex string into x, try

```
printf("0x%c%c%c%c\n", x[3],x[4],x[1],x[2]);
```